# Import local fonts from relative path in HTML file are not working

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to import local fonts from a folder from relative path in my index.html instead of cdn url but its not working out. I have tried following
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style/Material-Icons.woff2" as="font" cross-origin />` 
In the browser the fonts are loaded as i see them in the network tab with no error in loading. Also i am avoiding `@font-face`. Please guide me. Basically i am trying to replace following code:

```
     @font-face {
         font-family: "Material Icons";
         font-style: normal;
         font-weight:400
          src: url ("assets/style/Material-Icons.woff2")
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your font file is *included in the project*.

Also, try to specify the format like this -

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MaterialIcons"; // Removing space
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("./assets/style/Material-Icons.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

And use `font-family: 'MaterialIcons'` with these other font styles specified here. It should work.

Comment: Like i said, i am avoiding the use of ```font-face```